# Input integer files for checking inversion

Tags: c, algorithm

I am working on assignment for computing the number of inversion in an Array.

1. I need some sample input integer array files(for ex: InputArray.txt) with know inversion value to cross check my code. Any website to download the test set or how could I create one with known inversion value
2. My input file is having 100000 values, if I use long int count_inversion, then for this file the values overflow. Meaning it shows -ve value as inversion count.
   What type should I use for this

Comment: I have tried with small array. In this inversion count is correct.

Comment: write a bruteforce and compare answers for small array sizes say 1000 ( generate randomly ) against your actual program.

Answer (score 0):

Array of 100000 can have up to n * (n - 1) / 2, which for 100000 is 4,999,950,000 which doesn't fit into `long int`. Try using `long long int` ( 2^63 - 1 is the maximum value  of signed `long long` ).